# Activerecord, how to chain multiple condition on a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find a way to create a query for my product database.

I have these models

```
class Category < DatabaseProducts::Base
 has_many :category_searches
 has_many :products
end 

class Product < DatabaseProducts::Base
 belongs_to :category
 has_many :products_features
end 

class Feature < DatabaseProducts::Base
 has_many :products, through: :product_features
 has_many :product_features
end 

class ProductFeature < DatabaseProducts::Base
 belongs_to :feature
 belongs_to :product
end 

class CategorySearch < DatabaseProducts::Base
 belongs_to :category
end
```

Basically is a product database, and every product has some features, and values are stored in the `ProductFeature` join table.
Here is the structure, `presentional_value` is for the view, `raw_value` is for the search

```
create_table "product_features", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "raw_value"
    t.string "presentional_value"
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "feature_id"
    t.boolean "searchable", default: false
    t.index ["feature_id"], name: "index_product_features_on_feature_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_product_features_on_product_id"
  end
```

I have a Vue frontend in this product database, and I have multiple searches. To create the search field I create the category_searches table.

```
create_table "category_searches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.integer "feature_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "search_type"
    t.string "search_options", default: [], array: true
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_category_searches_on_category_id"
    t.index ["feature_id"], name: "index_category_searches_on_feature_id"
  end
```

Every night, when I import the new products in my database, I create new records or I update this table: for every searchable feature I store every possible searchable value.

For the TV Category, for example, in this table I have

```
category_id: 5
feature_id: 124
search_type: boolean
values: ["Yes","No"]

category_id: 5
feature_id: 235
search_type: options
values: ["OLED","LCD","QLED"]
```

In my Vue Frontend, for every category, I use the records in this table to draw the search interface, so when I select something the frontend send a request to my search API with these parameters:

```
category_id: 5
search_options: {"124" => "Yes", "235" => "OLED" ...}
```

Basically I have to search every product with `category_id=5` where `search_options`.

Here I stop: I don't know how build the query.

I know that I have to join the products table and the products_features table. 
And I know how to ask to Activerecord

"*Find Products where raw_value == ?*" or "*Find Products where feature_id= ?*"

It's a simple chained where. But I don't know how to ask ActiveRecord:

"*Find Products where `ProductFeature` with feature_id=124 has the raw_value of "Yes" and where the feature_id=235 has the raw_value of "OLED" and...* "

Comment: what database are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An AND clause won't really give you the result you want. What you want is an to use an OR clause and GROUP and HAVING:

```
f_id = ProductFeature.arel_table[:feature_id]
raw = ProductFeature.arel_table[:raw_value]
Product.joins(:product_features)
       .where(
          f_id.eq(124).and(raw.eq("Yes")).or(
            f_id.eq(12345).and(raw.eq("No"))
          )
        )
       .group("products.id")
       .having(Arel.star.count.eq(2))
```

This results in the following query:

```
SELECT "products".*
FROM   "products"
       INNER JOIN "product_features"
               ON "product_features"."product_id" = "products"."id"
WHERE  ( "product_features"."feature_id" = 123
         AND "product_features"."raw_value" = 'Yes'
          OR "product_features"."feature_id" = 12345
             AND "product_features"."raw_value" = 'No' )
GROUP  BY "products"."id"
HAVING ( count(*) = 2 )
LIMIT  ?
```

Which returns all products that have at least two matches in the join table.

You might want to use a JSON/JSONB column instead of a string column for the value storage. This will help you mitigate one of the biggest problems with the EAV pattern which is the headaches of typecasting everything into a string column.

On Postgres (and probably MySQL) you can use `WHERE (columns) IN (values)` to compose a simpler and more effective query:

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_features
  has_many :features, through: :product_features

  def self.search_by_features(*pairs)
    t =  ProductFeature.arel_table
    conditions = Arel::Nodes::In.new(
        Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new( [t[:feature_id], t[:raw_value]] ),
        pairs.map { |pair| Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(
            pair.map { |value| Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(value) }
        )}
    )
    Product.joins(:product_features)
      .where(
        conditions
      ).group(:id)
      .having(Arel.star.count.eq(pairs.length))
  end
end
```

Usage:

```rb
Product.search_by_features([1, "Yes"], [2, "No"], [3, "Maybe"])
```

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT     "products".*
FROM       "products"
INNER JOIN "product_features"
ON         "product_features"."product_id" = "products"."id"
WHERE      
  ("product_features"."feature_id", "product_features"."raw_value")
  IN 
  ((1, 'Yes'),(2, 'No'),(3, 'Maybe'))
GROUP BY   "products"."id"
HAVING     ( COUNT(*) = 3) ) 
LIMIT $1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try later. Yes, I think I will keep the string for the presentational value that is the value I use on the view but I will switch to jsonb for the raw value so I don't have to cast type... now I have weights and every measure as a string... :-/

Comment: thank you it works and it's very fast...
Now I try to learn the query to manage different conditions, not only equal but maybe a range of screen sizes... I will try!

Comment: All that beautiful `arel` you might as well clean this `.having("count(*) = ?", pairs.length)` to `Arel.star.count.eq(pairs.length)`

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky, I was trying to figure out how to do `count(*)` in Arel but could not get it right.

Comment: @max No problem. As an aside you can use this for `Model.arel_attribute` too e.g. `Product.arel_attribute(Arel.star)` will result in `products.*`

Answer (score 0):

How about using left joins?

```
Product
.left_joins(:product_features)
.left_joins(:features)
.where(product_features: {feature_id: feature_id, raw_values: "YES"})
.where(features: {feature_id: feature_id, raw_values: "OLED"})
```

if there is more table that can be joined, just add left joins statement and where statement again

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ActiveRecord supports such queries. You can use plain SQL, or [Arel](https://devhints.io/arel), or [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack), etc.

Cannot check at the moment, but Arel version may look similar to this:

```rb
products = Product.arel_table
result = params[:search_options].reduce(Product.where(category_id: 5)) do |scope, (feature_id, feature_value)|
  product_feature_table = ProductFeature.arel_table.alias("product_feature_#{feature_id}")
  join_clause = product_feature_table[:product_id].eq(products[:id]).
    merge(product_feature_table[:raw_value].eq(feature_value))
  scope.joins(product_feature_table.on(join_clause)
end
```